# Color of border on ImageView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I write an activity for a gallery. I have ImageView elements in GridView and I see a green border on ImageView when I focus on a given element. How can I change this default color of the border? Is it possible? I don't see any method which enables it.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's `android:listSelector="#..."` XML attribute in layout

Comment: When I set this property in GridView then it is applied to an entire view.

Comment: It seems that it's exactly what I need, but it doesn't work properly.